# Dynamically append populated calculated columns to produce result table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, dynamic-sql, temp-tables

USING: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0

I have a table `[Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts]` of updated per-State sales' order features that is structured as follows:

```
SELECT *  
FROM [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts]
ORDER BY State


State   BuildDate    Count_1    ...    Count_400
AK      2018-04-20   53200      ...    ...
AK      2018-06-05   53300      ...    ...
AL      2018-06-02   33800      ...    ...
AL      2018-03-09   33300      ...    ...
FL      2018-05-19   12000      ...    ...
```

I think something like this will work to generate a partial sample (for Count_1; in total there are 400, and the names are guesstimated age ranges and then other features about the orders):

```
CREATE TABLE [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts](
   State      VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Build_Date DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Count_1    INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts] .(State,Build_Date,Count_1) VALUES ('AK','2018-04-20',53200);
INSERT INTO [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts](State,Build_Date,Count_1) VALUES ('AK','2018-06-05',53300);
INSERT INTO [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts](State,Build_Date,Count_1) VALUES ('AL','2018-06-02',34000);
INSERT INTO [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts](State,Build_Date,Count_1) VALUES ('AL','2018-03-09',33000);
```

There are 400 such Counts.

Each time the underlying sales table is updated (the cadence is irregular), this table is populated with the associated Counts of different features of our sales in that State (how many initiated from email marketing, how many used a coupon, etc.)

I want a table that shows the difference between the previous survey of a State's order features and now, and the percentage change from the last to the most recent.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
SELECT name, column_id
INTO #CountColumns
FROM sys.columns AS c
WHERE c.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('[Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts]')
ORDER BY column_id    

DECLARE Count_Column_Cursor CURSOR SCROLL DYNAMIC FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM #CountColumns
    WHERE column_id > 2
DECLARE @Count_Column NVARCHAR(MAX)



OPEN Count_Column_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Count_Column_Cursor INTO @Count_Column
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = N'

    SELECT DISTINCT *
    INTO #Temp_1
    FROM(
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY [State] ORDER BY [BuildDate] ASC) AS Build_Count
    FROM [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts]) AS StateDates
    WHERE Build_Count <= 2
    ORDER BY [State] ASC, [BuildDate] DESC


    ;WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [State] ORDER BY [BuildDate]) AS rn
                    FROM #Temp_1)

    SELECT c1.[State],
        c1.[BuildDate] AS "Most Recent Build",
        c1.['+@Count_Column+'] - c2.['+@Count_Column+'] as "['+@Count_Column+'] Change",
        STR(ISNULL(((c1.['+@Count_Column+']-c2.['+@Count_Column+'])/NULLIF(CAST(c2.['+@Count_Column+'] AS NUMERIC(10,2)),0)),0) * 100 ,5,2) AS "['+@Count_Column+'] Percent_Change"
    INTO #Temp_2
    FROM CTE AS c1
    LEFT JOIN CTE AS c2
    ON c1.[State] = c2.[State] AND c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
    DELETE FROM #temp_2
    WHERE "['+@Count_Column+'] Change" is NULL;'
    PRINT @SQL
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
    ,N'@Count_Column'
    ,@Count_Column

FETCH NEXT FROM Count_Column_Cursor INTO @Count_Column;
END;
CLOSE Count_Column_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Count_Column_Cursor;
```

This errors, and from the print statement I get just as many prints of the queries I want (with 'incorrect syntax near ')'' after each one , like:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    INTO #Temp_1
    FROM(
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY [State] ORDER BY [BuildDate] ASC) AS Build_Count
    FROM [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts]) AS StateDates
    WHERE Build_Count <= 2
    ORDER BY [State] ASC, [BuildDate] DESC


    ;WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [State] ORDER BY [BuildDate]) AS rn
                    FROM #Temp_1)

    SELECT c1.[State],
        c1.[BuildDate] AS "Most Recent Build",
        c1.[Count_26-35] - c2.[Count_26-35] as "[Count_26-35] Change",
        STR(ISNULL(((c1.[Count_26-35]-c2.[Count_26-35])/NULLIF(CAST(c2.[Count_26-35] AS NUMERIC(10,2)),0)),0) * 100 ,5,2) AS "[Count_26-35] Percent_Change"
    INTO #Temp_2
    FROM CTE AS c1
    LEFT JOIN CTE AS c2
    ON c1.[State] = c2.[State] AND c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
    DELETE FROM #temp_2
    WHERE "[Count_26-35] Change" is NULL;
```

If I run one of those queries, it succeeds (with three different 'rows affected' messages, like I'd expect) - one such output, along with the other result sets:

```
    SELECT *  FROM [Database_STG].[org].[Order_Feature_Counts] 
    ORDER BY State
    SELECT * FROM #Temp_1
    SELECT * FROM #Temp_2
```

Returning:

1) the first table example

2) a table structured just like it, but only the two most recent builds of each state (i.e. if the initial table had 8 for California, the most recent two or else if Florida only had one record, just that one)

3) a table that looks like:

```
State   Most Recent Build   [Count_26-35] Change    [Count_26-35] Percent_Change
AK      2018-06-05          1500                    2.80
AL      2018-06-02          10400                   1.45
```

(numbers are jittered)

This #Temp_2 result is *almost* exactly what I want.

I want the State, the Most Recent Build and each Count's Change and Percentage Change - for all 400 of those counts!

So that I'll have State, Build Date, [Count_17-25] Change, [Count_17-25] Percent_Change, [Count_26-35] Change, [Count_26-35] Percent_Change, etc. (I've named these like Count_1, Count_2, etc. here in this question)

How do I append these individual queries' results 'left to right' to build out the full results table as they're calculated?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You did a nice job posting the code you have tried. But nobody can really do much with just that. What we really need is table structures, sample data and desired output so we can work on queries. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks, @sean-lange I'll edit and update this post!